# Run JSF project on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2

How can lunch JSP project on Tomcat? I copy `WebContent` folder to `webapp` folder of Apache but it can't find my jsp page, but if I change jsp to jsf (index.jsf) works fine. How can I solve this problem?

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Graph</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controler.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Upload</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Error:
type Status report

> message /Graph/index.jsp
>
> description The requested resource
>   (/Graph/index.jsp) is not available.

Comment: How does your tomcat folder structure look like and how do you try to call the jsps? In a jsf application you have to call them with the .jsf file extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not a problem. That's expected behaviour. You're just misunderstanding how the basic Servlet API works. You have configured the JSF-standard `FacesServlet` to listen on URLs matching `/faces/*` and you have configured Apache MyFaces specific `MyFacesServlet` to listen on URls matching `*.jsf` and `*.faces`.

To get JSF to run, you have to open the page in browser by an URL which matches the mapping of the `FacesServlet`. Given the fact that you've an `index.jsp` file and that your context path is `Graph` and that you have configured two JSF servlets on three different URL patterns, you can open the JSP by the following URLs:

- http://localhost:8080/Graph/faces/index.jsp (invokes `FacesServlet`)
- http://localhost:8080/Graph/index.jsf (invokes `MyFacesServlet`)
- http://localhost:8080/Graph/index.faces (invokes `MyFacesServlet`)

---

Said that, your configuration is unnecessarily overcomplicated. Get rid of the `MyFacesServlet` entry and all of its associated URL mappings (with the servlet name of `faces`). Just stick to the standard `FacesServlet` and use its mapping instead, or alter it instead. I personally recommend using `*.jsf`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you can just open the page by http://localhost:8080/Graph/index.jsf.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, your `welcome-file` won't work that way. Tomcat would give a HTTP 404 error on that (page/resource not found). You need to specify `index.jsf` as `welcome-file` and supply a concrete but **empty** `index.jsf` file in the same folder as your `index.jsp`. This way Tomcat will be fooled that the file exist and show the page by just calling http://localhost:8080/Graph.

---

If your concern is that it is possible to open JSF pages by their `*.jsp` extension which would result in a `RuntimeException: FacesContext not found` and you have actually no one JSP file which is to be served plain vanilla, then you can restrict direct access to JSP files by the following security constraint in `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to JSP files</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSP files</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

*(in JSF 2.0 this is by the way not needed anymore, with the default view technology Facelets it's possible to map the `FacesServlet` on just `*.xhtml`, which is the same as the default extension of Facelets files)*

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy your application with the tomcat manager

http://tomcatIP:8080/manager/html

there you can upload your application and it should run out of the box
if you have no idea what username and password you should type in, you have to configure your tomcat-users.xml